# Powershell 2 Select & Display Filename by Creation Date

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to find all instances of files with names like `VAT*.xls` where the creation date is less than 6 months ago. I have tried:

```
dir c:\vat*.xls -r | ? {($now -$_.lastwritetime).days -lt 300}
```

and

```
gci c:\vat*.xls -r | ? {($now -$_.lastwritetime).days -lt 300}
```

I know there is a file `VAT0210.xls` dated 1 April 2010 but neither query gives me that answer. What should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm slightly confused from your question. First you write that you want to get files where the *creation* date is less than six months ago, then you compare with `LastWriteTime`. And then you say you want *six months* but compare with *300 days*.

I'm following your prose here in the hope that was the correct one.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse -Include vat*.xls |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6) }
```

As you can see, it's fairly straightforward. Rewritten with aliases:

```
ls C:\ -r -i vat*.xls | ?{$_.CreationTime -gt (date).AddMonths(-6)}
```

If my initial guess as for your intentions was incorrect, feel free to adapt the code – should be trivial now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Johannes. Es ist jetzt klar.